# Javascript to change colors onChange options

Tags: javascript, html, list, html-select, onchange

My page has buttons to change the color of my Philip's hue lights -- but I want it to be a dropdown that will change as I change the option.
Here's what the current buttons look like:

```
<button class="lightbuttontall" onclick="lightcolor(1,colorred);">Light 1 red</button>
<button class="lightbuttontall" onclick="lightcolor(2,colorred);">Light 2 red</button>
<button class="lightbuttontall" onclick="lightcolor(3,colorred);">Light 3 red</button>
</p>
<p class="lightbuttonline">
    <button class="lightbuttontall" onclick="lightcolor(1,colororange);">Light 1 orange</button>
    <button class="lightbuttontall" onclick="lightcolor(2,colororange);">Light 2 orange</button>
    <button class="lightbuttontall" onclick="lightcolor(3,colororange);">Light 3 orange</button>
```

Then, in a separate js file I have this:

```
var colorred= "{\"on\":true,\"bri\":255,\"hue\":836,\"sat\":237,\"xy\":[0.6472,0.3316],\"ct\":500}"
var colororange="{\"on\":true,\"bri\":254,\"hue\":13390,\"sat\":251,\"xy\":[0.5663,0.3978],\"ct\":500}"
```

And this is what I'm trying to figure out.

```
<select name="jumpmenu" onChange="lightcolor(1,colorred);">
<option value="">Light 1</option>
<option value="1";>Red</option>
<option value="2";>Orange</option>
<option value="3";>Green</option>
<option value="4";>Blue</option>
<option value="5";>Pink</option>
<option value="6";>Pastel</option>
</select>
<script language="javascript">
function jumpChange(sel) {
    if (sel.value === "") return; 

    
sel.value = ""; 


};
</script>
```

*If I run that script, lightbulb one will change to red, but only red because that's the only  one it can recall. So I don't know how to tell the HTML to onChange go get colororange if I select option 2. Hope that makes sense.*

nnnnn helped me a lot with doing the data-switchNo code but I'm not sure if that will apply here or how to change it so it does. Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
<select name="jumpmenu" onChange="lightcolor(this);">
<option value="">Light 1</option>
<option value="colorred";>Red</option>
<option value="2";>Orange</option>
<option value="3";>Green</option>
<option value="4";>Blue</option>
<option value="5";>Pink</option>
<option value="6";>Pastel</option>
</select>
<script language="javascript">

 var colorred ="{\"on\":true,\"bri\":255,\"hue\":15331,\"sat\":121,\"xy\":[0.1721,0.0500],\"ct\":343}"
function lightcolor(light,color){
    execute('PUT', 'http://'+bridge+'/api/'+hash+'/lights/'+light+'/state', color);

}
    

function execute($method,$url,$message){
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open($method,$url,true)
xmlhttp.send($message);
}
</script>
```

This is where I'm at now.

Comment: Numerous syntax problems. Use a browser console to look at errors. Is very easy to do. Example : `colorred` and `colororange` should not have quotes around object or backslashes inside object. Missing a dot in front of `value` ..using  console will help

Comment: function jumpChange(sel) {
   if (sel.value === "") return; // do nothing if user selected first option

   var color = +sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-switchNo","color")
   lightswitch(color, sel.value==='on');
   
   sel.value = ""; // reset select to display the "Light Functions" option
   
   var colorred="{\"on\":true,\"hue\":13122,\"sat\":211,\"xy\":[0.5119,0.4147],\"ct\":467,\"transitiontime\":100";
   
}   That's where I'm at.... -_-

Comment: please create a simple demo with your code and html in jsfiddle.net. You didn't listen about removing quotes around object.  An object looks like: `var colorred={"on":true,"hue":13122,....}`

Comment: Will do, I'll show you why I'm confused about that as well.  http://jsfiddle.net/cgKp6/   here's my other js file though that communicates with the first buttons.  http://jsfiddle.net/sUPgU/

Comment: let me see this one if i get any other solution i will help you on this.

Comment: @ElRojito First explain me what exactly you want to do? Second provide the entire code like function that you are using to accomplish that and color values etc. Its not easy to get the solution without understanding the question.

Comment: Ok one moment. Basically, by going through an API I can change the color of the lightbulbs in my house. The above code, with the buttons, works. If I click the button, the light will change to either red or orange, or any other color I specify in the .js file using this  var **= "{\"on\":true,\"bri\":255,\"hue\":836,\"sat\":237,\"xy\":[0.6472,0.3316],\"ct\":500}"  But I want to now be able to move that into a drop-down menu. I'll add more to my first post.

Comment: @ElRojito  can you create fiddle of your code because still there is no lightcolor function in you above post and i am not getting where this code will apply where are the light bulbs its bit confusing. If cant see the actual situation i cant imagine what is the desired output.

Comment: Here's the original: http://jsfiddle.net/FPWZy/  The hash is a code from the router that is in charge of the lightbulbs. It's a JSON API http://rsmck.co.uk/hue like that. And when you click the buttons, it literally changes the color of my lightbulbs.  I'm very new to Javascript so this is kind of difficult! haha

Comment: see the link in which i have created the somewhat functionality you want if this work i will post the answer: http://jsbin.com/umuneb/1/edit

Comment: We're getting close! I think this is exactly what I need. It goes to get the CSS, but I need it to get the javascript variable from my other .js file. Do I just replace the ID with the var from the js file?

Comment: So I guess, my question is, how do I tell the HTML jumpChange to get the strings upon changing. Like get var colorred